# How to extract ids of images on a canvas when the images are drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cakephp

I have a finite state machine drawing tool and as you can see I have drag and drop for the different images( i.e: states and arrows) and for every arrow a div tag is getting created for the transition. Every state, arrow and transition alphabet has an id.

How can I extract the ids of all images that are present in the canvas when I press a button like save? Unfortunately, I can't save the image of the canvas so I need to someone figure out what all images are there in the canvas and save that information in an array or something upon which I could do some processing on the back end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sore the actual state somewhere, don't try to get back the rendered result, that's going to be a lot more difficult.

Comment: Any header as to how I do it? Like whenever I'm dragging an image, I store the id that time itself to an array?? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : You can't

Everything you draw on canvas cannot be "extracted" like moving DOM from one to another using appendChild(). So the only thing you can do is store the elements id when the drag event on the correspondent element is triggered, and then get all the stored ids when you click the save button.

---

EDIT

To be able retrieving and maintaining the elements id, you must implement an **undo** button and **validation** for input order. Every symbol that you draw on canvas will be exported into an image, hence you can then retrieve the id of individual symbol. The other drawing tools should be used **only** for highlighting important part of your canvas and shall not affect the finite state element (meaning you will use a different canvas element).

Here's an example :

```
<div id='input'>
  <button id='state'>State</button>
  <button id='transition' disabled>Transition</button>
  <button id='undo' disabled>Undo</button>
  <span id='info'></span>
</div>

<div id='canvas-container'>
  <canvas id='fsm' width='400' height='200'></canvas>
  <canvas id='preview' width='400' height='200'></canvas>
</div>

<hr/>
<div>History : <span id='history'></span></div>

<div id='limbo'>
  <!-- temporary canvas to get FSM symbol -->
  <canvas id='canvasLimbo' width='50' height='50'></canvas>
</div>
```

Also, here's the fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/tmpmachine/dn2p7zj5/172/

Comment: Hey, thanks!! Any headers as to how to save the ids when the event takes place??

Comment: header?.. do you mean a reference on how to do that? by the way, are you writing that program for mobile or desktop?

Comment: Yes please! maybe like a sample code?? And the program is for the desktop. And one more thing is, I gotta ensure that the transitions being saved are correct. The only way that can be ensured is if I save the ids of the two states, the transition alphabet and the arrow in the correct order. So maybe based on location in the canvas? How do I go about that?

Comment: I need to confirm several more things : "the transition alphabet" -- is that the 0 and 1? why can't you save the canvas to image? are you getting any error or you just don't want it to be saved as an image? ... btw if you are able to do the drag and drop thing, isn't that will be easier to store the ids when the drag event is triggered? why need a sample? (I've never try drag n drop so I don't know)

Comment: Yes, that's the 0 and 1. So for example, what I need to save is on a zero I go from the state a to state b and on a 1 go back to state a.

Comment: And I can't save the image coz I'm not supposed to do that.
What I needed a sample code for is that when I'm dragging the elements and saving their ids to an array..how do I make sure they are correct?? I have to ensure that when I'm saving the ids into for example an array, they are in the correct order. How can I tackle the case when I delete the zero transition from state a to b and enter another transaction for ex: 2. I would've to delete the previous id and enter the new one. How do I care that of this entire thing?

Comment: Ahh.. I've just realize something. Forget about it, it will not work since there's an option to erase. Let's think it another way.. so, I assume that the pencil, eraser, rectangle, circle, and font buttons are works exactly like ms paint, correct? If so, then, to be able to retrieve the element id, whatever those buttons do should not affect the element on the canvas... meaning you will need to implement a layered canvas. one canvas for each object, and you can only delete elements on canvas by clicking buttons in the sidebar (you will also need to implement a delete button for each elements)

Comment: if that meet your needs, I can try to make an example (although it will take some time)

Comment: Ooohh about that, I haven't worked on those things for now. And the eraser thing DOESN'T remove the images(worked on that already). Also, all the images get deleted by double right click. And those options already don't really affect my canvas. So basically I already have implemented the layered canvas thing i guess.

Comment: And I'm not planning to keep the pencil, eraser, rectangle, circle and text for this page. That's actually needed for another page.

Comment: Ok that's eliminate some problems. Could you provide some examples how to the insert, delete, and id retrieval should work? I still have difficulty to understand the case.. let's say you have A, ⇋, B and the succesfully retrieved ids are 1, 2, 3... if you delete ⇋, and redraw the symbol, what it should be? 1, 3, 2 or 1, 2, 3? Just edit your question above, so other people can understand better

Comment: After redrawing the symbol it should be 1,2,3 again. Does that kinda help?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Let's narrow this and back to the question. Sorry for the delayed answer.

Comment: You have no clue how helpful this has been for me. Thank you so much :) I have more than just a header to continue my work with.